# how to capture freehand writing in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin

I am working on an app to get free hand texts from a user and save as text file using xamarin forms but i am not quite getting any api or nugget or library for that any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `SignaturePad` component.

Check out this guide: [link](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/02/android-signature-capture-example.html)

You can also check out this implementation of the signature pad here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546864/xf-signaturepad-show-strokes-only-when-the-touch-ends/46669864#46669864)